# How to print a rhomboid shape in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I change this code that instead of printing the shape below, it prints it like a lozenge (rhomboid)?

```
def star (m):
    for i in range (m + 1):
        print ("*" * i)
    for i in range ( m + 1 ):
        print ("*" * (m - 1))
        m -= 1
```

Output

```
*
**
***
****
***
**
*
```

Comment: I've tried to draw the output picture here but I don't know why it's not possible.

Comment: the picture I want is a shape that instead of printing the first column under each other, it prints it in a way that the stars print in the middle so that the output picture becomes like a rhomboid. if it was possible I could type the picture but it seems it's not possible.

Comment: What is the `m` in the lozenge?

Comment: m is the number of the *. for example it's 4 here.

Comment: Sorry but I don't get it, please try to draw it... use `*` and spaces

Comment: OK I think I get it but it won't look nice if you print even number of stars, it won't be centered. Do you only want to print odd number?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Is this what you wanted?

```
def star(m):
    for i in range(1, m + 1):
        print(("*" * i).center(m))
    for i in reversed(range(1, m)):
        print(("*" * i).center(m))

star(10)
```

Output:

```
    *
    **
   ***
   ****
  *****
  ******
 *******
 ********
*********
**********
*********
 ********
 *******
  ******
  *****
   ****
   ***
    **
    *
```

Answer (score 0):

I like the following a bit better because it's more symmetrical:

```
def star(m):
    def star_line(n):
        print('{s:^{f:d}s}'.format(s='*'*n, f=m))

    for i in range(1,m,2):
        star_line(i)
    for i in range(m,0,-2):
        star_line(i)


star(5)
  *  
 *** 
*****
 *** 
  *
```

This solution uses the nice feature of Python's new(er) formatting syntax which enables you to specify the width of a field dynamically as well as the contents of the field: e.g. `'{s:^{f:d}}'.format(s='*'*3, f=5)` becomes `'{s:^5s}'.format(s='***')` which becomes `' *** '`.

Comment: yeah, it's symmetrical just for odd numbers. how about even numbers?

Comment: Well, one solution would be to put `i0 = 1 if m%2 else 2` before the first loop and then change `range(1,m,2)` to `range(i0,m,2)`

Answer (score 0):

A [lozenge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lozenge) is equilateral, a [rhomboid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhomboid) typically not. For illustration, I will do a rhomboid, but allow it to be equilateral.

To define a function, you should first specify the domain, in this case positive ints (or include 0 if you wish).

Functions should generally return an object that can be compared with the desired output for a given input.  You can then write an automated test for example outputs. In this case, the function should produce an iterable of strings.  The desired output can most easily be represented as a tuple or list of strings and the function output converted if necessary.

```
r43 = (
'****',
' ****',
'  ****',
)

def rhom(width, height):
    if not(isinstance(width, int) and width > 0 and
           isinstance(height, int) and height > 0):
        raise ValueError('width and height must be positive ints')
    stars = width * '*'
    for i in range(height):
        yield i * ' ' + stars

out43 = tuple(rhom(4, 3))
print(r43 == out43)
for line in out43:
    print(line)
```

prints

```
True
****
 ****
  ****
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def print_lozenge(num):
    str = '*'
    str_2 = str + (num - 1) * ' *'
    size = 2 * num - 1
    for n in range(num):
        print str.center(size, ' ')
        str += ' *' 
    for n in range(num):
        str_2 = str_2[: -2]
        print str_2.center(size, ' ')

print_lozenge(5)

    *    
   * *   
  * * *  
 * * * * 
* * * * *
 * * * * 
  * * *  
   * *   
    *
```

Answer (score 0):

I think This is what You're looking for:

```
for i in range(lines+1):
if i<=middle:
    for j in range(0, (middle-i)):
        print(end=' ')
    for j in range(i):
        print('*',end=' ')
else:
    for j in range(i+middle, lines+1, -1):
        print(end=' ')
    for j in range(i, lines+1):
        print('*', end=' ')
print()
```

Comment: What is `lines`? What is `middle`? Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.